# Hadoop Configuration in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I need to get hold of the current Hadoop `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` in my **Spark** job, for debugging purposes. Specifically I need to get `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` for a path with the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path#getFileSystem(conf: Configuration)` method

Given a `org.apache.spark.SparkContext`, is there a way to get the `Configuration`?

Comment: `sc.hadoopConfiguration`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set configration as per below code

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("my.mapreduce.setting","someValue")
```

Comment: Your answer implicitly answers my question: I don't need to set any configuration just get the Configuration object